# Why doesn't the compiler resolve implicit constrained type variables inside a function?

Tags: haskell

Here's the code:

```
class Problem p where
    readProblem :: String -> p
    solveProblem :: p -> String

readAndSolve = solveProblem . readProblem
```

And this is the error message GHC yields:

```
Ambiguous type variable `b0' in the constraint:
  (Problem b0) arising from a use of `readProblem'
Probable fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
In the second argument of `(.)', namely `readProblem'
In the expression: solveProblem . readProblem
In an equation for `readAndSolve':
    readAndSolve = solveProblem . readProblem
```

As I understand, I have to somehow tell the compiler that the `Problem` instance used by `solveProblem` and `readProblem` is the same type, but I see no way to declare that. And why can't it figure that by itself?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need not tell the compiler that it has to be the same type, the compiler figures that out by itself. However, it can't figure out *which* type to use. The canonical famous example of the problem is

```
foo = show . read
```

If `foo` had a legal type, that would be

```
foo :: (Read a, Show a) => String -> String
```

Now, how could the compiler determine a?

Your `readAndSolve` would have the type

```
readAndSolve :: Problem p => String -> String
```

Comment: Deleted previous comment. Ok, I get it now. Can I tell the compiler to just use the only instance available in scope and throw a compilation error if there are more (or less) than one available?

Comment: No, that's not possible, the compiler operates on an open-world-assumption, as far as the compiler knows, more instances can be defined elsewhere. So it never picks the only instance in scope on its own.

Comment: What is the right idiom for this type of abstraction then? I want to write a library that encapsulates UI of solving a problem and abstracts over the exact type of problem.

Comment: That's hard. Possibly the best way is to have one `Problem` type with constructors for the different types of problem and have `readProblem` figure out which constructor to return, then `solveProblem` goes `solveProblem (Type1 description) = solveType1 description` etc.

Comment: If there is only one instance, why make a type class at all?

Comment: @DanielFischer, thanks! Though I'm still hoping there is an extension-agnostic way to do this.

Comment: @augustss only one instance *in scope*

Comment: So only one instance in the program then, because instances have global scope.